# couldn't add my jaas config file to the jdk/security/java.security

Tags: java, tomcat, jaas, java.security

so am trying to build a webapp with tomcat and jaas as authentication and my jaas config file is named as lord.config and when i try to add the path in java.security file which is located in JAVA_HOME/conf/security and try to run the web app it throws an error

```
java.lang.SecurityException: java.io.IOException: Configuration Error:
   No such file or directory
```

the path that i added in java.security is:

```
login.config.url.1=file:"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\testtc\webapps\testjaas\WEB-INF\classes\lord.config"
```

and this is the  actual path of the lord.config from cmd

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\testtc\webapps\testjaas\WEB-INF\classes
```

the code of lord.config file

```
LorduJaas {
    LoLoginModule required;
};
```

and i tried adding and removing "" for spaces  neither did work.. what should i to add my config file to the java.security file?

Comment: have any ref? like from where you do the code?

Comment: https://youtu.be/guHkUICbvbY so i did exactly like he told yet caught this error

Comment: timestamp : 5:50

Comment: Have you tried to put the slashes in the other direction? These might be seen as escape characters.

Comment: tried that tooo nothing positive

Comment: i removed the quotes then changed the slash direction now i got something  else, it says
`java.lang.SecurityException: java.io.IOException: Configuration Error:
        Line 2: expected [controlFlag], found [null]`

Comment: That means the file is now loaded, but it's not a valid JAAS configuration format. Please search for examples online, or check the official documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/LoginConfigFile.html).

Comment: i have editted the question.. tha config seems right i have added the code too

Comment: can you share your workspace like a github link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems for the path I need to change it to the other slash as it is considered as an escape sequence changing it did the magic as follows

`login.config.url.1=file:"C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/testtc/webapps/testjaas/WEB-INF/classes/lord.config"`